# When on a non handled exception, how to catch the current variables too?

Tags: java, exception

I have created a structure to catch all non handled exceptions on the system and send them by e-mail.

But, I need a way to catch the current variables of the method that has thrown the exception too.

I know this is possible in PHP (log the current variables, event using $GLOBALS), but how we can do this with Java?

This is very important for us to really understand what caused the exception.

The process need to be automatically too, because we can't put try catch on all of the system methods, but the exception handler class need to find a way to get this variables. But what is this way?

Comment: by `variables of the method` do you mean method parameters? Or all local variables as well?

Comment: Sounds like a thread dump to me.  You don't get that with Java exceptions.  I would question any system that sent every variable in an email.  That's potentially insecure.  Better to write them to a log and have developers look at that.  You want to restrict access.

Comment: Parameters will be good, but local variables could be important too. If just the parameters is possible thats fine...

Comment: If you want the catch to see the variables, define them outside of the try block. Initialize them within the try block if necessary.

Comment: Yes, using just the java exception stacktrace is not possible. But I can't believe that this is not possible with java..

Comment: @GarouDan: It shouldn't surprise you; by the time you're handling the exception, according to your question, the method that threw it *has terminated*. Its arguments and variables are long out of scope. It's nice that PHP has some special handling for this, but Java doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. When an exception is thrown, Java just records the call stack (i.e. method pointers) which it then translates into method signatures (without arguments) and line numbers (if they are available).

The local variables and method parameters are not recorded so at the time when you catch an exception, they are not accessible anymore.

There is no cheap or simple way to achieve what you want. This is part of the cost you pay for Java being much faster than PHP.

If you use techniques like AOP, you can [log method parameter when a method is called](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html) to a file but that still doesn't allow you to pass them to an exception handler. Also accessing local variables is hard even with AOP.

You could buy a product like [dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/index.html) which allows rewriting byte code to add log statements to the code at runtime.

Or you can wait for errors to come in. Usually, the clump in certain areas. Then add log statements to those vulnerable places or throw new exceptions which show you interesting local variables.

Comment: I agree to a certain extend. Just two additions: a) dynatrace is free for your own local use. b) you can configure which method arguments you want to capture but you dont automatically get all variables - hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is basically debugging state. That triggered me to search around a bit and found this:

https://github.com/ankon/attachable-debugger

and this

https://www.takipi.com/

Hope it helps/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the methods in which the exceptions are occurring, you can't (not without some instrumenting tool that injects code into the class files). There is no way to access the arguments to / variables in the method that threw the exception *later*, after that method has been terminated by a throw, in a handler for the exception that was thrown.

So your choices are:

1. Modify all the methods to catch exceptions and rethrow with the details, or
2. Modify all the methods to log their variables before doing operations that may cause exceptions

Both are ugly, and both involve modifying all the methods.

You're probably better off not trying. Just capture the stack trace of the exception (and any inner exception and/or suppressed exceptions), and if you need precise variable state information, you'll have to replicate the error and debug.

Or if you really, really need the info, you'll need to locate and use a tool that can inject code into the class files to record the information.